# Huge overhead to loading StanfordOpenNLP model in Java?

Tags: java, memory, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to use StanfordNLP to do coreference resolution on chunks of text relating to a given topic, and while trying to load in the StanfordCoreNLP model, it at first completely ran out of memory while loading models, but now is still taking upwards of 15 minutes to load.

I have code like:

```
 public Map<Integer, CorefChain> getCoreferences(String text) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

    pipeline.annotate(document);

    return document.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation.class);
}
```

Is this unavoidable by design? Will it even be possible to do coreference resolution like this in a production application where anything more than 10 seconds is unacceptable?

Comment: What?! "Will it even be possible to do coreference resolution like this in a production application where anything more than 10 seconds is unacceptable"?

Comment: Yes? Is it not possible to find coreferences in a given text in less than 10 seconds assuming the model has been loaded?

Comment: It really depends on the sentence. The longer sentence you have, the more it will take to find the corefrence. in my experience, after loading the model it would take at most 2 seconds for each sentence.

Comment: You can take a look at Illinois Curator if you need a faster package: http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/18

Comment: Do you know of any docs that explain how I could use it for coreference detection? Also how long do you think the boot time is for this vs. the Stanford package, and also once the program is started up and the models and loaded into RAM, they won't need to be reloaded unless the application restarts, correct?

Comment: The code is pretty self expressive; no need to document. Just read the function titles, you will see how to use it.

Comment: On my computer(16 GB RAM, 3.7 GHz, 4 Cores) it takes like 1 minute.

Comment: Based on the function titles it seems there are many ways, can you humor me with an example?

Comment: What?? Example for what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's much faster if you don't instantiate *StanfordCoreNLP*
inside your method. Store it as a class variable.

More specifically, move the following to outside your method:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

Hope it helps! ;)

Comment: Note, depending on your usage, this may assume that StanfordCoreNLP is thread safe, which [it is](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/old-news.shtml).